# How do I access a list where "li" elements contain it's child "a"?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var array = [];

<ul>
<li><a href="#"> First </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Second </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Third </a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to put every "a" element into array. After I access to a "li" element, I can't go any further in reaching element "a".

I know it looks easy, but I can't figure it out for some reason, please help

Comment: Do you need an array of all `li` that contain an `a` or do you need an array of all `a` that are inside an `li`?

Comment: What context is this? I this inside the browser or using a driver? Why do you wan this information? What do you intend to do with the `a`?

Comment: @Reyno array of all "a" that are inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what your after here. But here is a simple example of how you can get these elements in a browser.

```js
var array = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
console.log(array);
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> First </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Second </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Third </a></li>
</ul>
```

the query `li a` says select all `a` contained in a `li` tag. Docs on [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)